# Azure Machine Learning - Recommender web service

Tags: azure, machine-learning

We’re trying to create a “next steps” recommender for our system: *Given a user and a context, we want a model that can give suggestions on what next steps the user might want to take.*

The matchbox recommender takes ratings, users, and items.  In our case, the **next steps** are items, the **combination of a user and their context** is the users, and the **usage data** is the ratings.

“Ratings”:

```
UserID  ScreenID    Rating
1       ScreenA       50
1       ScreenB       35
3       ScreenA       55
3       ScreenB       60
3       ScreenC       10
5       ScreenA       50
5       ScreenB       35
5       ScreenD       10
```

“Users”:

```
UserID  EmployeeID  Role            ContextCategory   ContextTask
1       078570      Representative  C                 Assignment/Reassignment
3       076545      Representative  A                 Assignment/Reassignment
5       076545      Representative  G                 Assignment/Reassignment
```

I’ve trained a model, created a predictive experiment, and published web service.  I had to change the web service input to ask for the combination of a user and their context (the user features, essentially), and expected the web service to give me suggestions based on other “users” that were similar:

[image: Azure ML Predictive Experiment]

However, when I test the webservice, it just returns a list of all trained users and their suggestions, not a suggestion for the new/cold user I specified on the input.

> Result: {"Results":{"output1":{"type":"table","value":{"ColumnNames":["User","Item 1","Item 2","Item 3"],"ColumnTypes":["String","String","String","String"],"Values":[["1","ScreenA","ScreenB","ScreenC"],["3","ScreenA","ScreenB","ScreenC"],["5","ScreenA","ScreenB","ScreenC"]]}}}}

There’s lots of documentation/examples about creating the training model for the Matchbox Recommender, but most of them take an item as input, and give recommended items as an output.  I can't find any examples that take a user as input, and turn it into a useful webservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cold start problem. To allow user with no ratings, you need to train the recommender with user features - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn905846.aspx

Here is an example where user and item features are passed for the cold start cases - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Recommender-Restaurant-ratings-2

Here is predictive experiment for the above case showing how to setup experiment for web service in such a case - https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Recommender-Restaurant-ratings-Predictive-Exp-2

Comment: Thanks for the links, neerajkh!  The root of my problem was that I needed two web service inputs - to substitute for the user-item-rating and user-context.